# I am getting error messages concerning my coding. I know Scanf is not a java function, so I am hoping to get help converting it

Tags: java, average

I know that scanf is not a java function, so i'm hoping someone can help me to understand how to convert this.  Research on this topic is difficult to piece together.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    int main (){
        int counter;
        int number;
        int total;

        float average;

        total = 0;
        counter = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter the number 0 to end: ");
        Scanf("%d", &number);

        While (number != 0) {
            total = total + number;
            counter = counter + 1;
            System.out.println("Enter the number 0 to end: ");
            Scanf("%d", &number);
        }

        if(counter != 0) {
            average = (float) total / counter;
            System.out.println("Average is %.2f\n", average);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No valid numbers have been entered.");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooo, what exactly did you try, in which way didn't it work, and what is your exact question ? This looks like C code pasted into a Java class...

Comment: I think that's where I may have gotten confused.  I used another type of code for javascript.  I am watching and reading different tutorials, so I think I may have gotten mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the changes done to your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class one {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int counter;
        int number = 1;
        int total;
        float average;
        total = 0;
        counter = 0;



        while(number != 0){
             System.out.println("Enter the number 0 to end: ");
             number = Scanner.nextInt();
             System.out.printf("%d", number);

            total = total + number;
            counter = counter + 1;


    }
        if(counter != 0){

        average =  ((float)total /(float)counter);

             System.out.printf("Average is %.2f\n", average);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No valid numbers have been entered.");
            //return 0;
         }
     }
}
```

First the Scanner takes the value the user entered. `number = Scanner.nextInt();` This must be done inside your `while loop` since its the one that check the condition.

The next thing I changed was `average = (float) total / counter;`

This casts the total value only to a float. use brackets to both ends.

`average =  ((float)total /(float)counter);` like this

Comment: Did that work for you?  It brought up 22 new errors when tested.

Comment: Yes I tested this I'm pretty sure this is corect.

Comment: @JoshuaTimms I updated the code including the full content. It's checked and its working. If it does't its something to do with how you compile.

Comment: wow!  It worked!  I had to fix one minor tweak, but it worked.  Unfortunately, not the way I expected it to.  I was hoping to create a program where I could add several numbers and it creates the average for the total.  But this only took one number and created the average.  Do you know what I can do to fix this?  Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @JoshuaTimms It should take multiple numbers. Check the `while(number != 0){` loop the loop will iterate until user enter 0. And users input is taken inside the loop so it will not loop forever.

Answer (score 2):

**use input like this**`

```
public class seting{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`
int total = 0;
System.out.printlnln("Enter the value of total :");
total = scan.nextInt(); // use  integer input
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same name for the object as for the class. Change Scanner initialization as follows:

```
Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Replace all your scanf statements with the below:

```
number = scanObj.nextInt();
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  It's difficult understanding this code.  But now I am getting a new error message, but it is the only one now.  It says, "C:\Java\Average.java:30: error: no suitable method found for println(String,float)
 System.out.println("Average is %.2f\n", average);"
           ^

Comment: Use printf instead of println. And please grab a Java book :)

Comment: Java supports printf - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: I am attempting to understand the material, but I am new to this, so understand that.  I am trying things from everyone's comments, but nothing seems to be working.  I think my coding just may downright be wrong.

Comment: That's ok. Java has it's learning curve. I thought the println was the only error you were getting.

Comment: so I should replace all of the lines that contain "println" and use "printf" instead?

Comment: Just use printf where you're doing formatting for the output.